# .bookmark = .lastmodified triggers ODBC Call Failed AND my error handler is not working to diagnose it

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, dao

Sorry for 2 problems in one questions, but both the code AND the error handler to get more info on the code problem are failing.  I use Access 2016 front end and SQL Server 2012 back end.

1. I insert a new record via DAO recordset.  The record inserts fine.  After the .Update line successfully processes, however, the ".bookmark=.lastmodified" line triggers an ODBC Call Failed error.
2. I've inserted error trapping to get more info on the above-mentioned ODBC error, but I get a type mismatch on the "For Each MyError In DBEngine.Errors" line.

Help on either one would be so appreciated!

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub Command5_Click() 'ADD
Dim ctl As control
Dim rstReg As dao.Recordset
Dim NewID as Long
On Error GoTo trap
If IsNull(Me.lstCustomers) Then
    MsgBox ("You must select a customer")
    Exit Sub
End If
Set ctl = Forms!frmmaintrn!lstSessions
Set rstReg = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("trnRegistration", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
With rstReg
    .AddNew
    Select Case Me.txtRegType
    Case 1 ' floating
        !FloatClassID = Forms!frmmaintrn!fkClassID
        !fkClassSchedID = 6760
    Case 2 'registered
        !fkClassSchedID = Forms!frmmaintrn!fkClassID
    End Select
    !DateEntered = Date
    !fkCompanyID = Me.lstCustomers
    !SalesRep = Forms!frmloginnames!lstOwner
    !fkUserTypeID = Me.cboUserType
    !fkOrderTypeID = Me.cboOrderType
    !VerifDate = Me.VerifDate
    .Update
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
    NewID = !RegistrationID
End With
trap:
Dim MyError As Error
MsgBox Errors.Count
For Each MyError In DBEngine.Errors
With MyError
    MsgBox .Number & " " & .Description
End With
  Next MyError
End Sub
```

And here are my references in case these have to do with the error trapping problem.  I've tried to add the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library, but I get a message that this "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library"

[image: References]

Comment: I'm beginning to fear that my table is corrupt.  Every time I try to add a record manually right from the table, I get an "Invalid Cast Specification Error".  Is there a way to test to see if a table is corrupt?  It has been behaving strangely in other ways too, such as sometimes when I add a record and then try to edit or delete it, I will get an error message that another user is trying to edit the table, which is not possible.

Comment: There are some SQL Server datatypes or specifications that don't work well with Access. Can you add the CREATE TABLE statement for your backend table?

Comment: In newer Access versions, DAO is included in the DB engine object library. Put the cursor into `dao` and press Shift+F2 to see it:  `Library DAO --   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL --   Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library` (for Access 2010)

Comment: @Xstian: Before adding a new tag to lots of questions, you should provide a tag wiki for it. `data-access-object` seems redundant since it's already covered by `dao`.

Answer (score 0):

One immediate fix is to change the declaration of MyErrors

> DBEngine.Errors Returns an **Errors collection** that contains all of
>   the stored Error objects for the specified object. (Not and Error
>   object)

Then use `For Each` to go thru errors - should return the proper ODBC error you're looking for.

Here's an example from Microsoft

```
ODBCErrHandler:
   Dim errX As DAO.Error

   If Errors.Count > 1 Then
      For Each errX In DAO.Errors
         Debug.Print "ODBC Error"
         Debug.Print errX.Number
         Debug.Print errX.Description
      Next errX
   Else
      Debug.Print "VBA Error"
      Debug.Print Err.Number
      Debug.Print Err.Description
   End If
   Resume Exit_function
End Function
```

> EDIT - Add recordset suggestion to remove dbSeeChanges-
>
> my mistake - I see you have SQL Server 2012 back end - I think that
>   requires dbSeeChanges

Maybe wrap the line in a check for Bookmakable recordset

```
If .Bookmarkable = False Then
    Debug.Print "Recordset is not Bookmarkable!"
Else
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
Endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with checking the `.Bookmarkable` property first, but ...

Your problem with the `MyError` variable is the declaration.  Both Excel and DAO have an `Error` object, but the Excel reference comes ahead of the DAO reference.  Use an explicit declaration for this variable:

```
Dim MyError As DAO.Error
```

This should at least help you resolve the problem